# Pascal string representation in Hex-Rays Decompiler of IDA Pro

Tags: ida, disassembly, static-analysis

I'm trying to prettify a representation of Pascal-string "Could not access file "" in Hex-Rays decompiler's output. As you can see below,
[image]

now its type is **char[25]** due to inclusion of hexademical string length. How can I force IDA to perceive Pascal-strings properly during their depiction in Hex-Rays pane? I want to see for all Pascal-string in corresponding window something like

```
LODWORD(v90) = ConcatenateStrings_R8_R9_to_RCX(v140, 255i64, "Could not access file \"", v158);
```

I tried to change types via "Set item type..." as showed below.
[image]

Unfortunately, these options didn't help.

Comment: Create a custom struct with length as the first member and assign that type.

Comment: Did you mean to create a structure with the first byte for string length and the other bytes as array of zero length?

PascalStr struc ; (sizeof=0x1, mappedto_104, variable size)
len db ?
str db 0 dup(?)
PascalStr ends

But in this case I get
ConcatenateStrings_R8_R9_to_RCX(v188, 255i64, v188, &stru_7FF6202878C4);